# Dynamic list constraint on Alfresco

Tags: constraints, alfresco

I'm trying to follow the examples provided in [this post](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/jbarmash/2008/08/08/dynamic-data-driven-drop-downs-for-list-properties/), to create a dynamic list constraint in Alfresco 3.3.

So, I've created my own class extending `ListOfValuesConstraint`:

```
public class MyConstraint extends ListOfValuesConstraint {
    private static ServiceRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public void initialize() {
        loadData();
    }

    @Override
    public List getAllowedValues() {
        //loadData();
        return super.getAllowedValues();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAllowedValues(List allowedValues) {
    }

    protected void loadData() {
        List<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();
        String query = "+TYPE:\"cm:category\" +@cm\\:description:\"" + tipo + "\"";
        StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef("workspace://SpacesStore");
        ResultSet resultSet = registry.getSearchService().query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE, query);
        // ... values.add(data obtained using searchService and nodeService) ...

        if (values.isEmpty()) {
            values.add("-");
        }
        super.setAllowedValues(values);
    }
}
```

`ServiceRegistry` reference is injected by Spring, and it's working fine. If I only call `loadData()` from `initialize()`, it executes the Lucene query, gets the data, and the dropdown displays it correctly. Only that it's not dynamic: data doesn't get refreshed unless I restart the Alfresco server.

`getAllowedValues()` is called each time the UI has to display a property having this constraint. The idea on the referred post is to call `loadData()` from `getAllowedValues()` too, so the values will be actually dynamic. But when I do this, I don't get any data. The Lucene query is the same, but returns 0 results, so my dropdown only displays `-`.

BTW, the query I'm doing is: `+TYPE:"cm:category" +@cm\:description:"something here"`, and it's the same on each case. It works from initialize, but doesn't from getAllowedValues.

Any ideas on why is this happening, or how can I solve it?

Thanks

**Edit:** we upgraded to Alfresco 3.3.0g Community yesterday, but we're still having the same issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This dynamic-list-of-values-constraint is a bad idea and I tell you why:

The Alfresco repository should be in a valid state all the time. Your (dynamic) list of constraints will change (that's why you want it to be dynamic). Adding items would not be a problem, but editing and removing items are. If you would remove an item from your option-list, the nodes in the repository with this property value will be invalid.

You will not be able to fix this easily. The standard UI will fail on invalid-state-nodes. Simply editing this value and setting it to something valid will not work. You have been warned.

Because the default UI widget for a ListConstraint is a dropdown, not every dropdown should be a ListConstraint. ListConstraints are designed for something like a Status property: { Draft, Waiting Approval, Approved }. Not for a list of customer-names.

I have seen this same topic come up again and again over the last few years. What you actually want is let the user choose a value from a dynamic list of options (combo box). This is a UI problem, not a dictionary-model-issue.  You should setup something like this with the web-config-context.xml (Alfresco web UI) or in Alfresco Share. The last one is more flexible and I would recommend taking that path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (I know, I'm a little late... :). By the time you wrote your answer, I had already been transferred into another project within my company, so I never had a chance to try your suggestion. Anyway, thank you, especially for the warning about the dynamic list of values!